Nx doesn't generate types (only zipped)
When I'm serving my webpack application through nx the types generated are all zipped. How can I set up properly the generation of the remote types?
This are my configurations:
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const ModuleFederationPlugin =
  require('@module-federation/enhanced').ModuleFederationPlugin;
const path = require('path');
const commonConfig = require('../../webpack.react.common.js');

module.exports = (_, argv) =>
  merge(commonConfig, {
    entry: './src/main.tsx',
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
      port: 4201,
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/apps/info_plus'),
    },
    plugins: [
      ...(!argv?.env?.standalone
        ? [
            new ModuleFederationPlugin({
              name: 'info_plus',
              filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
              runtime: false,
              exposes: {
                './InfoPlusApp': './src/app/App.tsx',
              },
              shared: {
                react: {
                  singleton: true,
                  requiredVersion: '^18.0.0',
                },
                'react-dom': {
                  singleton: true,
                  requiredVersion: '^18.0.0',
                },
              },
            }),
          ]
        : []),
    ],
  });


And here is the common config:
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.base.json'),
      }),
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
    },
  },
};


After some research I found that to manage the type generation we should work with the dts option from the module federation plugin.
So to always generate them use:
dts: {
   generateTypes: {
        typesFolder: '../../../tmp/@mf-types',
        deleteTypesFolder: false,
   },
}

In particular, I used the following configuration using argv passed by webpack:
module.exports = (_, argv) =>
// Webpack config
plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
     name: 'name',
     filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
     exposes: {
       './Module': './src/module/index.tsx',
     },
     dts: {
          generateTypes:
            argv?.env?.nodeEnv === 'production' 
            ? true
            : {
               typesFolder: '../../../tmp/@mf-types',
               deleteTypesFolder: false,
             },
     },
    
  }),
]

